# Material-ui - TextField - Can't change helper text error color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a `form` with a very awkward background color. Would like to change the color of the helper text of the Outlined `TextField` when it is in an error state but can't seem to override it. It persists the red.

See [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9rppp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by CSS specificity (the base style has more specific classname, i.e. `MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error` than the overriding style class). It's [recommended](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14681) to use `&$` syntax under this circumstance:

```
const helperTextStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: 4,
    '&$error': {
      color: 'white'
    }
  },
  error: {} //<--this is required to make it work
}));
```

You can also refer to [this section](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) for an example and a bit more explanation.

Comment: I was forced to end up using `!important`... like `color: 'white !important'`

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, the error text color is generated under the following className: `.MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error` 
So overriding error rule alone is not enough. 
This will do the trick:

```
const helperTextStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: 4,
    color:'black',
  },
  error: {
    "&.MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error" :{
      color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
  },
}));
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ibd6r)

Comment: Spent a few good hours trying to figure out how to change helperText color - and what worked for me was this! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to customize your Mui Theme as follows:

```
const Theme = {
    components: {
        MuiFormHelperText: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    color: "red"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

See https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/ for more information.

Answer (score 2):

i found one solution to change the color of text field.

```
<TextField
      error
      id="filled-error-helper-text"
      label="Error"
      defaultValue="Hello World"
      helperText="Incorrect entry."
      variant="filled"
```

/>
here you can see error which is Boolean, so you might be having validation like YUP, if you do then you pass it like this.

```
<TextField
  error={!valid}
  id="filled-error-helper-text"
  label="Error"
  defaultValue="Hello World"
  helperText="Incorrect entry."
  variant="filled" />
```

here i am changing color base on valid keyword.

Answer (score 1):

For those who search how to edit the color without theme overrides :

```
<TextField FormHelperTextProps={{ sx: { color: 'primary.main' } }} />
<TextField FormHelperTextProps={{ sx: { color: 'success.main' } }} />
<TextField FormHelperTextProps={{ sx: { color: 'red' } }} />
```